# How do I turn off "Sign in to Microsoft Store" notifications?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

More often than I would like, I see this banner:

[image]

I would like to stop getting this notification.

In Settings -> Notifications & actions, I have the Microsoft Store option turned off. Is this controlled by a different setting somewhere?

I have Windows 10 Enterprise, and something like uninstalling the store or disabling all notifications isn't going be what I'm looking for.

Comment: When you say you have it turned off what do you mean exactly.  What version of Windows 10 are you using.  What edition of Windows?  Edit your question

Comment: @Ramhound Did you go to Settings -> Notifications & actions? There is a switch/flag for "Microsoft Store" on the screen that Brian linked in his answer, but I had it off when the dialog popped up, so that one doesn't help.

Answer (score -3):

Settings | System | Notifications - turn them off for apps - this is the only way I see - you cannot uninstall the Microsoft Store :-(

[see pic of dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk92E.png)

Comment: You **absolutely can uninstall** the Windows Store UWP application.  This suggestion basically disabled all notifications.  I doubt that’s what the author wants to have happen

Comment: so is the answer to simply uninstall the Windows Store app (however that is accomplished - maybe share that process?)? I doubt that is what the author wants to have happen as well perhaps? If it is, I am glad to delete or change my answer, etc or have you answer the actual post - you know just to help folks in the future...